# Pasar un char a int en una estructura de datos en c++

Tags: c++

Tal vez esto sea fácil pero estoy empezando en esto y quisiera pasar un `char` a `int` en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Googleando llegas mas rápido

Comment: de todos modos: Sea 'a' una variable tipo char y 'b' tipo int, ---> int b = (int)a; debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: buenas.
Desde mis inicios de estudios que no veo c++, pero alomejor este link te sirve.
Suerte...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 4):

He encontrado una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439589/3683321) en SO en inglés que me ha parecido interesante si lo que buscas es convertirlo en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) aunque para [c](/questions/tagged/c) también valdria creo.

Puede utilizar el hecho de que las codificaciones de carácteres para los dígitos están en orden desde 48 (para '0') hasta 57 (para '9'). Esto es cierto para ASCII, UTF-x y prácticamente todas las demás codificaciones (ver comentarios más abajo para más información sobre esto).

Por lo tanto, el valor entero para cualquier dígito es el dígito menos "0" (o 48).

```
char c = '1';
int i = c - '0'; // i es ahora igual a 1, no '1'
```

es lo mismo que

```
char c = '1';
int i = c - 48; // i es ahora igual a 1, no '1'
```

Sin embargo, encuentro el primer c - '0' mucho más legible.

Además si quieres asegurarte que el carácter a convertir sea un dígito antes de realizar la conversión, puedes utilizar la función [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/?kw=isdigit)

```
char c = '1';
int a = isdigit(c);
if(a==0){
     //no es un digito
}else{
     //es digito
     c = '1';
     int i = c - '0';
}
```

Por otra parte existe la función [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) que te permite pasar un *string* de caracteres a int:

```
char *num = "1024";
int val = atoi(num); // atoi = ASCII TO Int
```

Comment: Muchas gracias 

Comment: Hola @JMolina si te ha servido para solucionar tu problema te invito a que marques la respuesta como correcta, además te invito a que hagas el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por SO español para que veas como funciona el sitio.